# Reversing Docker Compose file from running stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to get a docker compose configuration file from an already running stack on docker?

Comment: I have the same question, @Likqez did you find any way to get this?

Comment: no i sadly did not!

Comment: I had post a question on docker forums, but no response from there, it means only possible through a bash or python script.

Comment: If you find such a script please share it on here c: